# Delay rendering router outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Am new to Angular6 and facing this scenario:

I have a API at app.component.ts. After getting the data am storing it in session storage for the other component(i.e. abcComponent) usage.

The issue here is, by the time abcComponents tries to fetch from session, the API in app.component is not completed and hence its not stored in session storage

using router-outlet to load my other components.

I tried using resolve, but the service in resolve is getting called for everycomponent. So any suggestions would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way this is solved in Angular is:

1. Create a service and mark it as `@Injectable`.
2. In the service call the API with the Angular HttpClient Module that returns observables.
3. In the abcCompoent inject the service and subscribe to the observable that calls the API and then use the data as your component sees fit.

I know this might sound confusing but here you have the Angular documentation with a nice example: [Communicating with backend services using HTTP - Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Basically I want to call that API only once in the application and the response data will be cached to be used in the other components.

Comment: Then the usual way is to use NgRx. (https://ngrx.io) so you configure your store and read the global state and subscribe for state changes.

Answer (score 0):

you want to call the api in abccomponent, not app.component. and abccomponent should have some kind of spinner to show the user that data is being loaded.

Comment: Also if components are hidden until data arrives Angular has no binding errors.